# Do I need to get my baggage and proceed in custom control as a transit visitor to US via Canada?

Tags: transit, customs-and-immigration, luggage, canada, air-canada

I'm traveling from *Istanbul* to *San Francisco* via *Toronto* with **Air Canada** (*for both*) and I'm wondering if I have to **get my luggage and head to the customs in *Canada***?

Currently holding a Turkish passport and I got a transit visa for Canada. Also, the time between two of the flights is about 1 hour and 50 minutes.

My flights:

Istanbul to Toronto **(Air Canada)**

*<1 hour and 50 minutes between flights>*

Toronto to San Francisco **(Air Canada)**

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

You will clear US Customs and US Immigration at Toronto prior to arriving in the United States, in a procedure called Preclearance. You no longer need to collect your baggage for inspection but of course US Customs may inspect your bag if they wish. You do not need to go through Canadian customs. The procedure is well sign posted: follow the purple signs. When you arrive in San Francisco you have already completed immigration formalities and your flight is treated as a domestic arrival.